# New to subqueries, why can't I just use multiple where statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I'm not understanding the purpose of subqueries in SQL, . I'm confused on how they differ from/how they're more beneficial than doing something like working it into your where statement, creating a case statement, or using a join or something? Can someone give me an example of when you might need a subquery? To my current understanding it's just helpful to do something like calculate an average and then also pull up other information from the table in the same query. I just simply don't understand, something isn't clicking right and I'm currently blaming my instructor because she's a new one and doesn't seem to explain anything in a way that makes sense to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Comment: What kind of subquery? Some people refer to derived/inline tables as "subqueries". There are also correlated subqueries, scalar subqueries...

Comment: In ways a subquery behaves something like a subroutine/function/procedure call if you're familiar with other languages.